# Electrical engineering Proteus

Tags: proteus

How can I get a toggle DPDT switch that can simulate the forward, neutral and backward position of a DC motor using Proteus?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm working with a linear actuator and I want to do the electric diagram using proteus

Comment: And I'll use a DC motor to represent the linear actuator. I need 3 toggle dpdt switch. How can I get this switch on proteus